# UISwitch doesn't seem to show the right state

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have four UISwitches on a page. 
Im testing AnimalSwitch to see if it works.
By default it’s on, when I switch it off and go to a different view controller and back, the test label says it is still switched off, but the switch image shows it is on.
This is the code of the Switch im trying to change(the others i’ve left untouched until i fix this one). 
The other switches Are named the same, only the word “Animal” changes.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  AnimalSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
  if (defaults.object(forKey: "AnimalswitchState") != nil) {
    AnimalSwitch.isOn = defaults.bool(forKey: "AnimalswitchState")
  print("switched")
}
```

Comment: It's fixed! The problem was somewhere else in my code Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `userDefaults` is updated? Remember you need to `synchronize()` to apply changes. And, when are you updating the switch and the label? You should be updating the label using the event value changed of the switch.

Comment: i think synchronize() no more needed in swift

Comment: I looked it up and your right from version 8.0 its no longer needed.